# Какие запятые можно безболезненно убрать?

Tags: пунктуация

> В горах, во время нашей дневной трапезы, на старинную, подробно
>   реконструированную территорию фазенды, прямо в ресторан, ворвался
>   табун пятнистых полудиких лошадей.

По авторской интонации нужны все; придётся объясняться (мне).

---

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Из абсолютно необходимых запятых я усматриваю только одну - после "старинную". Остальное - сугубый факультатив:

*В горах во время нашей дневной трапезы на старинную, подробно
реконструированную территорию фазенды прямо в ресторан ворвался
табун пятнистых полудиких лошадей.*

Comment: Не знаю насчёт интонации, но если её не учитывать, я бы последние две убрал.

Comment: «Подробно реконструированную » следовало бы заменить на «аутентично воссозданную».

Comment: Вмешательство в авторскую лексику и стилистику, в то время как ошибки - нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере, который Вы приводите, выстроилась цепочка уточняющих обстоятельств. Однако прямые значения первых двух обстоятельств не указывают на уточняющий смысл. Такой смысл  возникает в условиях контекста. При сохранение прямого значения выделение не требуется.

Вот что говорится в Полном академическом справочнике под редакцией Лопатина:

> Уточняющий смысл члена предложения может возникнуть в условиях
> контекста, хотя прямые значения обстоятельственных слов и не указывают
> на такое соотношение: *И вдруг, у самого поворота в Суходол, увидели
> мы в высоких мокрых ржах высокую и престрашную фигуру* (Бун.) — под
> воздействием значения обстоятельства *вдруг* у следующего
> обстоятельства — *у самого поворота в Суходол* — выдвигается на первый
> план временно́е значение (в тот момент, когда подъезжали); *В этот
> раз, подле больной матери, Султанмурат особенно остро почувствовал*
> *запустение жизни без отца* (Айтм.) — временно́е значение сочетания в этот раз снимает пространственный оттенок в значении обстоятельства
> *подле больной матери*.
>
> Подобные члены предложения при сохранении своего собственного значения
> выделения знаками не требуют, ср.: *В этот раз подле больной матери
> Султанмурат особенно остро почувствовал запустение жизни без отца*.

Хотя обстоятельства  "в горах","прямо в ресторан" являются обстоятельствами места, всё же они отвечают на разные вопросы: *где? куда?* и по своему лексическому значению немного отстоят друг от друга.

Поэтому запятую после "прямо в ресторан" лучше не ставить.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж. Если Вы не согласны с какими-либо из моих мелких поправок в Вашем тексте, не сочтите за труд - верните всё на свои места.

Comment: Все нормально, Галина! Спасибо за поправки.

Answer (score 2):

**В горах, во время нашей дневной трапезы, на старинную территорию фазенды (подробно реконструированную), прямо в ресторан, ворвался табун пятнистых полудиких лошадей.**

Предложение в заданном виде не читается (смысл теряется, нарушается легкость восприятия текста).

Или пожертвуйте этой подробностью ("подробно реконструированную"), или заключите её в скобки.

**Дополнение**

Еще раз читаю предложение, и вот какие размышления. Правила правилами (всегда можно найти нужное правило), но **смысл важнее**, о нем прежде всего надо думать.

Здесь уточняющие обособленные обстоятельства (небольшого объема) уточняют **ситуацию,** причем **с нарастающей экспрессией**, они передают **свежесть восприятия события,** поэтому обособление нужно обязательно оставить. А вот справочную информацию - в скобки! Или вообще из текста убрать.

Answer (score 0):

А если так:
В горах, во время нашей дневной трапезы на старинной, подробно реконструированной территории фазенды, прямо в ресторан ворвался табун пятнистых полудиких лошадей.

Или так:
Во время нашей дневной трапезы в горах, на старинную, подробно реконструированную территорию фазенды, прямо в ресторан, ворвался табун пятнистых полудиких лошадей.

"Подробно" — может, до иголки, до тонкости, до мелочей?

Comment: Так смыслы нельзя ж менять! Мы не знаем, сколь далеко от табуна расположились трапезничающие... Римма, я не сочинение школьника редактирую, а многоглавную книгу! У меня сроки, скорость! Автора нельзя переписывать!